# Does completing the side-mission Lock and Load have any in-game effect?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Handsome Jack mentions that if you get some loaders to the moonshot that "they'll join you on the moon's surface."

Does this actually have an in game effect, and if it does is it affected by the number of loaders that survive?

Comment: I haven't found anything that states this.  I want to say no.  It's just a mission.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall ever seeing any loaders on the surface as a result of this mission.

The [fandom wiki doesn't say anything about it](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Lock_and_Load), either.

So, no.

Comment: I have no way of testing this now, but I've noticed that during the story mission "Beginning of the End", two loaders were sent down by Jack... the same number I'd saved earlier.  However, I have no way to test if that's directly related or just coincidence.

Comment: @Powerlord The wiki page for that mission doesn't mention any loaders. When do they come in?

Comment: Right before you enter the excavation site in Vorago Solitude during the "Locate main excavation site" goal.  I want to say they show up as soon as you activate the New-U station nearby.